# convert MySQL data to sentence case

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, uppercase

I have an inherited Wordpress database where the past four years worth of code have been written in UPPERCASE.

I'd love to convert the posts and their titles to sentence case, but can't seem to find a way to manage this. From what I can see, there's no straightforward way to do this in MySQL and whilst I see there's a `ucfirst` function in PHP, I'm struggling to find out how to expand this to work on a full post and how to tap into the database to do this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use mysql replace method like this :

```
 UPDATE table_name SET field_name = replace( field_name, 'string_to_find', LOWER('string_to_replace') ) ;
```

I'm not sure if this works properly , but I'm sure that's must be it , so play with the code , I dont have mysql to check :d